# Чем отличаются value += 5 и value = value + 5?

Tags: python, python-3.x

После того, как я нашёл различия между arr.append() и arr = arr + [5] при передаче arr как параметра функции, я задался вопросом, имеют ли какое-то подобное отличие, связанное с ссылками на объекты и локальностью переменных, комбинированные операторы += и оператор + с присваиванием, когда выполняются внутри функции. В интернете ответа не нашёл, поэтому пишу сюда.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для неизменяемых объектов результат этих операторов будет один и тот же. После изменения придется явно возвращать значение или же передавать значение в функцию внутри list.

Похоже у вас есть пробел в [изменяемых/неизменяемых объектах](https://medium.com/@meghamohan/mutable-and-immutable-side-of-python-c2145cf72747) Python, советую изучить подробнее.

Comment: Пробелов нет, к счастью, вся статья ясна. Просто я не уточнил этого в вопросе – подразумевался список, который передаётся ссылкой в аргументе. Мы можем изменять объект, находящий вне функции, по ссылке прямо внутри функции. Но такое работает только с изменяемыми объектами.